# Getting More Place information from MapKit on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Specifically I am trying to get the "type" of location that you can see here:

[image]

`Elementary School` in this example.

In my results I have a `MKMapItem` or a `MKLocalSearchCompleter` that I can use to try to find this information. Is it possible?

Comment: There is a property in `MKMapItem` called [`pointOfInterestCategory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/3143415-pointofinterestcategory). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Sweeper I don’t think so. In the example above, I don’t see a ‘pointOfInterest’ category for “Elementary School”